# load specific div content using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using $.ajax to load the page content. In response I am getting whole html document as a string but I want to get the only particular div content from the response by using id of the div. I can't change the response and I can't use $.load method. Thanks in advance.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: ajax_url, 
    type: "GET", 
    dataType: "html" 
}).done(function(data) {
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
});
```

Comment: Just show a bit of the code?

Comment: $.ajax({
        url : ajax_url,
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "html"
    }).done(function(data) {
   // here i want to fetch the specific div content from response.
 }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

 });

Comment: What about using [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) with HTML fragment part?  (this accepts any knid of CSS selector, not only ID)

Comment: try using $($.parseHTML(response)).filter("#success");

Comment: @Antony should be `find()` not `filter()`

Comment: @Antony Thank you very much. It is working fine now..

Answer (score 1):

In your `.done()` method:

```
.done(function(data) { 
    $('#target').html($(data).find('#specificDivId'))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As AJAX returns a plain text, you can transform it to jQuery DOM element, modify it and append (or replace HTML) to your HTML.

For example, this way:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: ajax_url, 
    type : "GET", 
    dataType : "html" 
}).done(function(data) { 
    var obj = $(data);
    $("#yourdiv").html(obj.find(".something").html());
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

});
```

I have used `.find(".something")` because I do not know the format of received message. You can use any jQuery methods.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is basically what ajax shorthand method [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) using page frament is doing:

```
$('#divToAddContent').load(ajax_url + ' #divToGetContent');
```

*(note the space at starting fragment selector string)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOM parser.

```
$.ajax().success(function(data) {

  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");

  // doc is a DOM now

});
```

More information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DOMParser